# Find out how many times a regex matches in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way that I can find out how many matches of a regex are in a string in Python? For example, if I have the string `"It actually happened when it acted out of turn."`

I want to know how many times `"t a"` appears in the string. In that string, `"t a"` appears twice. I want my function to tell me it appeared twice. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to count overlapping matches? Is the regex "friend of a friend" once or twice in the string "friend of a friend of a friend"?

Comment: You need overlapping?  So, if the match pattern is "aa" and the source string is "aaaa" the correct answer is 3?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The existing solutions based on `findall` are fine for non-overlapping matches (and no doubt optimal except maybe for HUGE number of matches), although alternatives such as `sum(1 for m in re.finditer(thepattern, thestring))` (to avoid ever materializing the list when all you care about is the count) are also quite possible. Somewhat idiosyncratic would be using `subn` and ignoring the resulting string...:

```
def countnonoverlappingrematches(pattern, thestring):
  return re.subn(pattern, '', thestring)[1]
```

the only real advantage of this latter idea would come if you only cared to count (say) up to 100 matches; then, `re.subn(pattern, '', thestring, 100)[1]` might be practical (returning 100 whether there are 100 matches, or 1000, or even larger numbers).

Counting **overlapping** matches requires you to write more code, because the built-in functions in question are all focused on NON-overlapping matches. There's also a problem of definition, e.g, with pattern being `'a+'` and thestring being `'aa'`, would you consider this to be just one match, or three (the first `a`, the second one, both of them), or...?

Assuming for example that you want possibly-overlapping matches *starting at distinct spots in the string* (which then would give TWO matches for the example in the previous paragraph):

```
def countoverlappingdistinct(pattern, thestring):
  total = 0
  start = 0
  there = re.compile(pattern)
  while True:
    mo = there.search(thestring, start)
    if mo is None: return total
    total += 1
    start = 1 + mo.start()
```

Note that you do have to compile the pattern into a RE object in this case: function `re.search` does not accept a `start` argument (starting position for the search) the way *method* `search` does, so you'd have to be slicing thestring as you go -- definitely more effort than just having the next search start at the next possible distinct starting point, which is what I'm doing in this function.

Answer (score 69):

```
import re
len(re.findall(pattern, string_to_search))
```

Comment: len(re.findall(pattern, string_to_search, re.IGNORECASE)) if you don't want to miss the pattern in different case

Answer (score 20):

I know this is a question about regex. I just thought I'd mention the [count](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method for future reference if someone wants a non-regex solution.

```
>>> s = "It actually happened when it acted out of turn."
>>> s.count('t a')
2
```

Which return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of the substring

Answer (score 11):

You can find overlapping matches by using a noncapturing subpattern:

```
def count_overlapping(pattern, string):
    return len(re.findall("(?=%s)" % pattern, string))
```

Comment: Simple and clean solution to the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried this?

```
 len( pattern.findall(source) )
```

Comment: Does this count overlapping? He said it needs to support that. (Seems like that would be really difficult to perform)

Comment: The doc says: Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
print len(re.findall(r'ab',u'ababababa'))
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid creating a list of matches one may also use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re#re.sub) with a callable as replacement. It will be called on each match, incrementing internal counter.

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.matched = 0
    def __call__(self, matchobj):
        self.matched += 1

counter = Counter()
re.sub(some_pattern, counter, text)

print counter.matched
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```
ptr_str = lambda pattern,string1 :print(f'pattern = {pattern} times = {len(re.findall(pattern,string1))}')
pattern = 'AGATC'
str='AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGATCATAGGTTATATTGT'
ptr_str(pattern,string1)
```