# Count number of times a substring occures within split txt file

Tags: python

I have a .txt file called test1.txt which contains:

```
apple
P apple apple
P apple
Pbanana apple P apple apple apple
```

I split it into catagories based on the letter P using this code:

```
import re

Apple_split = open("test1.txt").read().split("P")

print(Apple_split_split)
```

I now wish to count the number of times the word apple occurs within each split. Hopefully coming out with an output such as 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 or something like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374457/find-out-how-many-times-a-regex-matches-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: note that you `import re` but are not using it in the code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
f = open('test1.txt').read().split('P')
apple_counts = [segment.count('apple') for segment in f]
print apple_counts #[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
```

The above uses a simple list comprehension after splitting each segment by the `'P'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.count` within a list comprehension to apply it to each of the split segments.

```
with open('test1.txt') as text_file:
    print [segment.count('apple') for segment in text_file.read().split("P")]
```

Comment: I tried this but its just gives me the total number of apples. Im trying to find the number of apples in each split.

Comment: The list comprehension does exactly what you want. Try it as it is written here; it returns [1, 2, 1, 1, 3]. http://repl.it/VSm