# Python Count Characters

Tags: python

Write a program whose input is a string which contains a character and a phrase, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the phrase. The output should include the input character and use the plural form, n's if the number of times the characters appears is not exactly 1.
Ex: If the input is:

n Monday
the output is:

1 n
Ex: If the input is:

z Today is Monday
the output is:

0 z's
Ex: If the input is:

n It's a sunny day
the output is:

2 n's
Case matters. n is different than N.

Ex: If the input is:

n Nobody
the output is:

0 n's

This is what I have so far:

```
user_string=input(str())
character=user_string[0]
phrase=user_string[1]
count=0

for i in phrase:
    if i == character:
    count = count+1

if count!= 1:
    print(str(count) + " " + character + "'s")
else:
    print(str(count) + " " + character)
```

This works great for the phrases that have 0 characters matching. But its not counting the ones that should match.

Comment: Just an FYI, the 'str()' at the input is not necessary, `input` returns the entered value as a string by default

Comment: a closely related topic is disscussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374457/find-out-how-many-times-a-regex-matches-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Suggest just using `str.count`.

```py
user_string = input()
character, phrase = user_string[0], user_string[1:]
count = phrase.count(character)

print(f"{count} {character}" + ("'s" if count != 1 else ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = input()
chr = string[0]
phrase = string[1:]
count = phrase.count(chr)
print(count)
```

not as detailed as others but this got me a 10/10 on zybooks.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I see you are an new user on StackOverflow. It would be helpful if your answer had more explanation on why it is a good solution or more info about the syntax that would help educate others.

Answer (score 0):

We will take the user's input, with the assumption that the first letter is the one that you are counting, and find that character with `user_string.split()[0]`. We will then take all the other words from the user's input (with `user_string.split()[1:]`), join them with `''.join` and then explode them into a list of letters with `[*]`. We will return a list of "hits" for the character we are looking for. The length of that list will be the number of "hits".

```py
user_string=input()

numOfLetters = [letter for letter in [*''.join(user_string.split()[1:])] 
                if user_string[0]==letter]
print(f'Number of {user_string[0]} is: {len(numOfLetters)}')
```

```
t This is a test    # Input
Number of t is: 2   # Output
```

```
h Another test for comparison # Input
Number of h is: 1             # Output
```

Comment: This seems like a _very_ roundabout way to say `count = sum(1 for ch in s[1:] if ch == s[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_phrase=input()
letter=user_phrase[0]
if letter in user_phrase:
    if user_phrase.count(letter)>2:
        print (f'{user_phrase.count(letter)-1} {letter}\'s')
    elif user_phrase.count(letter)==1:
        print(f'0 {letter}\'s')
    else:
        print(f'{user_phrase.count(letter)-1} {letter}')
```

Comment: Could you add a comment that explains what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input()    
x = user_input[0]    
y = user_input.count(x) - 1

print(y)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to my zybooks lab it is not the best answer on the thread but is the second right after Chris's answer. Since his adopts the technique where you don't have to subtract one from your count. The techniques he employed are things to adopt imo.

```
phrase = input()
for letter in phrase[0]: 
    count = phrase.count(letter) - 1 #This counts the amt of letter in phrase, then subtracts 1 excluding index 0
    if count != 1: #1 isn't plural so to say "1 f's" doesn't make sense
        print(count, str(letter)+"'s") #sample output [4 f's]
    else: #and there we have it
        print(count, str(letter)) #sample output [1 f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
user_string = input()
character, phrase = user_string[0], user_string[1:]
count = phrase.count(character)
print(f"{count} {character}" + "'s" if count != 1 else f"{count} {character}")
```

Comment: This looks to be an attempt to correct Chris' answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
user_string=input(str())
character=user_string[0]
phrase=user_string[1:]
count=0

for i in phrase:
    if i == character:
        count = count+1

if count != 1:
    print(str(count) + " " + character + "'s")
else:
    print(str(count) + " " + character)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
letter_and_phrase = str(input())
number_times_char_appears = 0
begin_letter = letter_and_phrase[0]
split_phrase = letter_and_phrase[1:].strip(' ')

for letter in split_phrase:
    if letter in begin_letter:
        number_times_char_appears += 1
        
if number_times_char_appears > 1:
    print(f"{number_times_char_appears} {begin_letter}'s")
elif number_times_char_appears == 0:
    print(f"{number_times_char_appears} {begin_letter}'s")
else:
    print(f"{number_times_char_appears} {begin_letter}")
```